# How to get value from an object(collection)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I am trying to get value from mysql and compare it to requested value, so I can avoid dublicates, what am I missing cause it's not working. Help plz

```
if ($request->email == DB::table('people')->where('email', $request->email)->get('email')){
            return 'This e-mail is already registered';
        }
//I get [{"email":"random@gmail.com"}] type(object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the entry in the database exists directly using a query.

```
if (DB::table('people')->where('email', $request->email)->exists()){
    return 'This e-mail is already registered';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist